# How to remove webpack:// from sources in the browser

Tags: webpack, vue.js, production, webpack-production

I am using [this](http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/) webpack template for a Vue.JS website.

I deployed the app and it works well, but if you go to developer tools > Sources in Chrome, then under webpack:// you can see the components and the whole code. Is there a way to get rid of that? Or is this usual if you use webpack?

Thank you.

Comment: Why whould you want to do that?

Comment: I don't think anyone should have the possitbility to see the components, etc.

Comment: How are you generating the bundle (the app you deployed)?

Comment: The command is: npm run build

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That's because webpack generates [source maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Use_a_source_map) which show the original source code and structure.

For the webpack template, you should look for the `config/index.js` file,

and in order to skip the source map generation change `productionSourceMap` to `false`:

```js
module.exports = {
  dev: {
    (...)
  },

  build: {
  
    (...)

    productionSourceMap: false,
    // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#production
    devtool: '#source-map',

    (...)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 22):

if you are using vue-cli and have a vue.config.js file then you can simply just add it like this

```
module.exports = {
    productionSourceMap: false,
}
```

Comment: Lifesaver! 8> Should be as accepted one!