# Is it possbile to not to show source code in vue?

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I wonder if it is possible to disable webpack folder in inspect, so users cant see my source code?

And if it's not possible, can users change it and run it?

[image: example]

Comment: see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53310750/vue-spa-how-to-hide-vue-files-when-rendered-in-browser

Comment: All the Vue code is executed as a client in the browser, and should be always handled as unsafe. A user is always able to change or overwrite browser functionality. 

With this fact given its important to never trust client input. Make sure your backend only handle the input that it allowed for that user. When there is sensitive logic that never should be public, you should handle that in the backend of your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution, you can try this in the "vue.config.js"

```
module.exports = {
productionSourceMap: true,
}
```

This option will tell Webpack to exclude the source code. Could be a solution for you.

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Most commonly such a structured view is available only in `development` environment.

When the code is shipped to `production` environment it's normally minimized & bundled into one or several files which already makes it quite hard to read.

If you want to "hide" it from the user even further, you can use code obfuscation tools (you will likely need to pay for them) or move sensitive parts of your code to serverland.

Generally speaking, the only bulletproof way to hide the code from your users is never ship it to their browsers.

Whether the code is obfuscated or not, the user is alway able to change it & run. Obfuscation just makes it significantly more difficult.