# how to remove 'webpack://' from browser developer tool?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I'm making some web service using by vue.js with vue-cli.
But I encountered some problem.
In chrome,firefox browser or any other browsers , when i open developer tool, the tool shows me original codes in source tap -> webpack:// directory.

And i don't want to show my original vue source.
I have already tried the following solutions but they didn't work.

## [How to remove webpack:// from sources in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49096454/how-to-remove-webpack-from-sources-in-the-browser)

What can i do for hide 'webpack://' from developer tool??

I'm using vue3.

Comment: What exactly did you try? Source maps are responsible for that. Dev tools cannot physically show webpack:// and original source code if you disabled source maps.

Comment: @EstusFlask Sorry for reading lately :,(   
I just put `productionSourceMap: false,` in `vue.config.js` file ..

Comment: @EstusFlask But, nothing is changed.

Comment: Make sure you run production build, dev build isn't affected by this option, obviously. I cannot say anything about Vue 3 as it's not documented yet. Try to eject and see what's going on with sourcemap options in Webpack config.

Comment: @EstusFlask Oh, Thank you! So far, I have run my project in developer mode.    I didn't know difference between product build and developer build Thx!